# List index out of range error using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I am Using TensorFlow to create an image classification model. I have written the following lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random 
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import glob
from PIL import Image
```

--importing all my libraries

```
#newer code
dic = {}
# assuming you have .png format files else change the same into the glob statement
train_images='/Users/FOLDER/downloads/Boneage_competition/training_dataset/Resized/'

for file in glob.glob(train_images+'/*.png'):
    b_name = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]
    dic[b_name] = mpimg.imread(file)

dic_label_match = {}
label_file = '/Users/FOLDER/downloads/train.csv'
train_labels = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/FOLDER/downloads/train.csv')
for i in range(len(train_labels)):
    # given your first column is age and image no starts from 1
    dic_label_match[i+1] =  str(train_labels.iloc[i][0])
    # you can use the below line too
    # dic_label_match[i+1] =  str(train_labels.iloc[i][age])

# now you have dict with keys and values 
# create two lists / arrays and you can pass the same to the keram model

train_x = []
label_ = []

for val in dic:
    if val in dic and val in dic_label_match:
        train_x.append(dic[val])
        label_.append(dic_label_match[val])
```

-- appending each image to its corresponding label

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(12611,300,300,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
```

--Applying a model to the dataset

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

-- compiling my model

```
model.fit(train_x, label_, epochs=5)
```

Upon Running this code, I am greeted with an error message in the last line. The entire message is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ca24364bad96> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(train_x, label_, epochs=5)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    706     self._check_call_args('fit')
    707 
--> 708     func = self._select_training_loop(x)
    709     return func.fit(
    710         self,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _select_training_loop(self, inputs)
    498             self._distribution_strategy)):
    499       try:
--> 500         valid_adapter = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(inputs, None)
    501       except ValueError as data_failure_exception:
    502         valid_adapter = None

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    645 def select_data_adapter(x, y):
    646   """Selects a data adapter than can handle a given x and y."""
--> 647   adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]
    648   if not adapter_cls:
    649     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    645 def select_data_adapter(x, y):
    646   """Selects a data adapter than can handle a given x and y."""
--> 647   adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]
    648   if not adapter_cls:
    649     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in can_handle(x, y)
    451   @staticmethod
    452   def can_handle(x, y=None):
--> 453     handles_x = ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter._is_list_of_scalars(x)
    454     handles_y = True
    455     if y is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _is_list_of_scalars(inp)
    462       return True
    463     if isinstance(inp, (list, tuple)):
--> 464       return ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter._is_list_of_scalars(inp[0])
    465     return False
    466 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried adjusting the epoch number, as well as using other models to no avail.

If you have any ideas why this might be or any tips for my code, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error due to the following line

```
dic_label_match[i+1] =  str(train_labels.iloc[i][0])
```

Here you are indexing with 1 instead 0. So when you are executing the following line

```
label_.append(dic_label_match[val])
```

Your `label_` has value starting from `1, 2, ....` it should start from `0, 1, ...`.

Hence you can either change the line as follows

```
label_.append(dic_label_match[val - 1])
```

or you can change the following line

```
dic_label_match[i] =  str(train_labels.iloc[i][0])
```

Comment: I have updated the code, but can I ask what that does? I am still receiving the error in the next code block. --- as a side note, I forgot to define my loss f(x) in my code so I have updated my code in my question.

Comment: @John as you had not put the loss function details thats why I thought that might be the reason you are getting error. But as now u have updated the code, I have updated my answer accordingly---

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that, but unfortunately, I am still getting the error message. If you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate them but if not, that's totally fine.

Comment: Also (I apologise for commenting again) but for reference, both the image labels, as well as the CSV file, start their numbering from image #1377. Also, I have a test set and the corresponding, true, labels for this, but I have not since put these into the code. I am only trying to train the model right now. I don't know if any of this helps, but I thought I would mention it. Once again, thanks for all your help so far.